# Why does numpy's as_strided change array strides with (default) strides=None?

Tags: python, numpy

According to the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) the strides parameter of `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` defaults to the strides of the input:

> [...] The strides of the new array. Defaults to x.strides.

However, when I do the following, the strides change:

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

print("The following should be identical:")
foo = np.arange(100).reshape(10, 10)
print(f"Foo strides: {foo.strides}")
bar = as_strided(foo, (5, 5))
print(f"Bar strides: {bar.strides}")
```

produces:

```
The following should be identical:
Foo strides: (40, 4)
Bar strides: (20, 4)
```

I'm using numpy 1.19 in python 3.7.0. What is going on, and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a mismatch between the docs and the code. The [actual code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.19.0/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py#L37-L111) starts off like this:

```
# first convert input to array, possibly keeping subclass
x = np.array(x, copy=False, subok=subok)
interface = dict(x.__array_interface__)
if shape is not None:
    interface['shape'] = tuple(shape)
if strides is not None:
    interface['strides'] = tuple(strides)
```

so the real default for `strides` is whatever value the `'strides'` key has in `x.__array_interface__`. For a C-contiguous array, that value is `None` rather than an actual stride tuple, and the code goes on to produce a C-contiguous output instead of keeping the input strides.